# Which version of Xcode support iOS 12.2?

Tags: xcode, xcode10, ios12

I was running my self-developed software on my iPhone 7 which runs iOS 12.2 when an alert had popped up:

> This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 12.2 (16E5201e), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Answer (score 55):

You could follow these steps:

1. You have to download "device support files for the iOS" from [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E5212e).zip),

And if you need any other "device support files for the iOS" you could download from [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport),

2. Thin unzip it,
3. Then go to your application folder,
4. Right-click on the Xcode-Beta.app and choose Show Package Contents,
5. Navigate to Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOS.platform->DeviceSupport,
6. Then paste the file you downlaod in it.
   Other [resource](https://medium.com/swift2go/how-to-run-ios-12-on-real-device-using-xcode-9-51aa51df7c4).

Comment: Worked well. Thanks

Comment: I have Xcode 10.1 and I need to have the target deployment set to 12.2 which my ios device is on. How do I do that? I'm not quite understanding. I can't upgrade to Mojave and would like to keep using High Sierra OS. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to change the target deployment to 12.2 , just connect your iPhone or iPad then select it from simulator menu then run the your app, but make sure that you follow the steps above.

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

For Xcode Version 10

1. [Download 12.2 (16E226)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bctb49ujmg00br3/12.2%20%2816E226%29.zip?dl=1)
2. Copy 12.2 (16E226) directory to  Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode.app⁩ ▸ Show package Contents ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform⁩ ▸ ⁨DeviceSupport⁩
3. Quit Xcode and open again.

=> Update for iOS 12.3 step 1 -> 2 copy folder 12.2 (16E226) and rename 12.3 -> 3

Comment: Right click on "Applications -> Xcode" and then select "Show package Contents" to proceed with the rest.

Comment: After doing this I got new error 
Couldn't create workspace arena folder '/Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bwkkgfbrgtgsmffxqcifyjsoehdq': Unable to write to info file '<DVTFilePath:0x7fd15648d800:'/Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idaru-bwkkgfbrgtgsmffxqcifyjsoehdq/info.plist'>'.

Comment: Can you update the link to show that it is an immediate download and not a link to the source of the download. I was just going to see where it came from to then decide, if I knew it was dropbox I would NOT have downloaded it!

Comment: You don't need to download anything, just in point 2 rename the latest folder to 12.2 restart Xcode etc. and viola!

Comment: 12.2 (16E226).zip https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JVqo3gBDytaMYN1c0SBk-CUdipb4cBTc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 7):

You need Xcode 10.2 which is now available in the Mac AppStore and requires macOS 10.14.4. Direct download is not available right now.

Answer (score 5):

```
git clone https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport.git
cd iOS-DeviceSupport
sudo ./deploy.py -t /Applications/Xcode.app
```

> More detail: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: pretty handy ty

Answer (score 1):

If you already have folders from recent versions like below, you can often just duplicate the most recent one and rename it to whatever version Xcode asks for.

[image: Finder illustration]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10.2 beta 3 (current version)

Available for download here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: the download takes an estimated time of one hour, I am literally crying.

Comment: Xcode 10.1 would do. No need for the beta just to do this.

Comment: Matt,
How do I get xcode 10.1 to be able to see 12.2 in the target deployment list? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, the answer could be different.

If you want DEBUGGING (breakpoint, logging on console...) on your real device iOS 12.2, then you must have Xcode 10.2 (it's beta at this moment)

If you want to RUN your app on your device, you can use Xcode 10.1 (thought even Xcode 9 can do that). You can do that using beta distribution service like TestFlight, Fabric... Or by using Xcode, you can archiving your app, then drag & drop the .app file in your device.