# This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 12.3.1 (16F203), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I getting the following error when I run the app into device.

This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 12.3.1 (16F203), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

my Xcode is 10.1

Comment: Did you check [this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876861/which-version-of-xcode-support-ios-12-2?rq=1)?

Comment: there is no support files for 16F203 into that list

Comment: unfortunately there is no 12.3.1 profile available yet. I've just downloaded latest profile and renamed it suitably 12.3.1 (16F203) for the time being, removed the app and it worked. Xcode ver 10.1.

Answer (score 5):

Your current version of Xcode does not support the iOS 12.3.1 version of the SDK.

There are a couple of options available:

1. Update Xcode to the latest version
2. Download a add the required device support files to your current version.

You can download the support files [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport) or from the Apple Developer website. There is also instructions on where to place the files once downloaded

Comment: in those list 16F203 this file is not available.

Answer (score 5):

There may be problems with running your app on latest XCode version, but you can add supported devices to your current XCode's folder.

1. download version of required iOS from https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport
2. Put it to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` inside of XCode folder
3. Restart XCode

Comment: This worked for me. I had a (new stock) iPhone 7 running iOS 13.4, trying to use it with Xcode 11.3.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem , and here is the solution worked for me

You should make a folder named 12.3 (... what is written in your error message) in Program/Xcode-beta/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platforms/DeviceSupport/ and copy the files from 12.2 in there.

Close xcode completely and reopen it.

Now you can run your apps on iOS 12.3.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution for this change folder named 12.3.1.its working for me once we get 12.3.1 package content we will move corresponding place

Answer (score 0):

You should update your XCode to support all listed devices.

Comment: Actually my application is ready to deliver in this stage I want to update the Xcode is not good, from next onwards I update.

Comment: There will be no major issues in upgrading of Xcode

Comment: Yes, you can export your IPA file and add via iTunes to the respective device. (suggested for Developer mode only)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this problem on Device with iOS 14 and Xcode 11.5 Version

**_Download iOS 14.0 Zip from this link:** 
https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

**_and past the folder to:** 
`Xcode/Show Package Content/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` 
**_Quit and Restart both XCode and iPhone**

**_In XCode go to:** 
Window/Device and Simulator and Click on + Button
Select your device
Click Next and Click Done, and then build and run your XCode

**Note:** You can also clear your cache before the build and run your XCode 
**Hope this helps who faces this problem, cheers.**